# BibLaTeX doesn't work on my Mac with TexStudio

Tags: biblatex

The code works without errors when using Sharelatex.com. But it doesn't work on my Mac. I mean, everything is wonderful - just the biblatex part is bad.

Here an example of code and my problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
natbib=true,
style=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{src.bib}
%\addbibresource{src.bib}
\begin{document}
This is my example.\cite{Sh:1043}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My src.bib file (taken from the internet)

```
@article{FaSh:1042,
author = {Farah, Ilijas and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Farah, Ilijas and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {3,IL},
journal = {Journal of Institute of Mathematics at Jussieu},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1401.6689 },
pages = {1--28},
title = {{Rigidity of continuous quotients}},
volume = {15},
year = {2016},
},

@article{Sh:1043,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {Mathematical Logic Quarterly},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1412.0421 },
pages = {140--154},
title = {{Superstable theories and representation}},
volume = {62},
year = {2016},
},

@article{FiGoKrSh:1044,
author = {Fischer, Arthur and Goldstern, Martin and Kellner, Jakob and
 Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {CA,AT,AT,IL},
journal = {Archive for Mathematical Logic},
note = { arxiv:1402.0367 },
pages = {59 pps},
title = {{Creature forcing and five cardinal characteristics of the
 continuum}},
volume = {on-line},
},

@article{Sh:1045,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {preprint},
title = {{Quite free Abelian groups with prescribed endomorphism ring}},
},

@article{KmSh:1046,
author = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IN, IL},
journal = {Journal of Symbolic Logic},
title = {{RVM, RVC revisited: Clubs and Lusin sets}},
volume = {submitted},
},

@article{GaSh:1047,
author = {Garti, Shimon and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Garti, Shimon and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL,IL},
journal = {Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1609.00242 },
title = {{How you are with $\mathfrak{s}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$}},
volume = {accepted},
},

@article{Sh:1048,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {Fundamenta Mathematicae},
note = { arxiv:new },
title = {{Hanf number for the strictly stable cases}},
volume = {submitted},
},

@article{HeSh:1049,
author = {Herden, Daniel and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Herden, Daniel and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {G,IL},
journal = {preprint},
title = {{On group well represented as automorphic groups of groups}},
},

@article{MiSh:1050,
author = {Malliaris, Maryanthe and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Malliaris, Maryanthe and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {1, IL},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
title = {{Keisler's order has infinitely many classes}},
volume = {accepted},
},

@article{MiSh:1051,
author = {Maryanthe Malliaris and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Maryanthe Malliaris and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {1, IL},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
pages = {67 pps},
title = {{Model-theoretic applications of cofinality spectrum
 problems}},
volume = {appeared online},
},

@article{Sh:1052,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society},
note = { arxiv:math.LO1503.02423 },
pages = {5371--5383},
title = {{Lower bounds on coloring numbers from hardness hypotheses     in
 PCF theory}},
volume = {144},
year = {2016},
},

@article{ShWo:1053,
author = {Shelah, Saharon and Wohofsky, Wolfgang},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon and Wohofsky, Wolfgang},
fromwhere = {IL,AT},
journal = {Mathematical Logic Quarterly},
pages = {434--438},
title = {{There are no very  meager sets in the model in which both the
    Borel Conjecture and the  dual Borel Conjecture are true}},
volume = {62},
year = {2016},
},

@article{KpSh:1054,
author = {Kaplan, Itay and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Kaplan, Itay and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL,IL},
journal = {Mathematical Logic Quarterly},
pages = {530--546},
title = {{Forcing a countable structure to belong to the ground model}},
volume = {62},
year = {2016},
},

@article{KpLaSh:1055,
author = {Kaplan, Itay and Lavi, Noa and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Kaplan, Itay and Lavi, Noa and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL,IL,IL},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
pages = {259--287},
title = {{The generic pair conjecture for dependent finite diagrams}},
volume = {212},
year = {2016},
},

@article{BrLrSh:1056,
author = {Bartoszynski, Tomek and Larson, Paul and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Bartoszy\'nski, Tomek and Larson, Paul and Shelah,
 Saharon},
fromwhere = {1,1,IL},
journal = {Fundamenta Mathematicae},
pages = {101--125},
title = {{Closed sets which consistently have few translations covering
    the line}},
volume = {237},
year = {2017},
},

@article{DwSh:1057,
author = {Dow, Alan and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Dow, Alan and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {1, IL},
journal = {preprint},
title = {{Asymmetric tie-points on almost clopen subsets of
 $\mathbb{N}^*$}},
},

@article{RaSh:1058,
author = {Raghavan, Dilip and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Raghavan, Dilip and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {3,IL},
journal = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
title = {{On embedding certain partial orders into the P-points under
 RK and Tukey reducibility}},
volume = {appeared electronically},
year = {2017},
},

@article{HbSh:1059,
author = {Haber, Simi and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Haber, Simi and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL, IL},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1510.06581 },
pages = {226--236},
series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
title = {{An extension of the Ehrenfeucht-Fra{\"{\i}}sse  game for
    \mbox{first order} logics augmented with Lindstr\"{o}m  quantifiers}},
volume = {9300},
year = {2015},
},

@article{RaSh:1060,
author = {Raghavan, Dilip and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Raghavan, Dilip and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {3,IL},
journal = {Fundamenta Mathematicae},
note = { arxiv:LO/1505.06296 },
title = {{Two inequalities between cardinal invariants}},
volume = {accepted},
},

@article{Sh:1061,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
pages = {293--296},
series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
title = {{On failure of 0-1 laws}},
volume = {9300},
year = {2015},
},

@article{Sh:1062,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {preprint},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1706.01226 },
title = {{Failure of 0-1 law for sparse random graph in strong logics}},
volume = {Beyond First Order Model Theory},
},

@article{KmSh:1063,
author = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IN, IL},
journal = {Mathematical Logic Quarterly},
title = {{Clubs on quasi measurable cardinals}},
volume = {accepted},
},

@article{Sh:1064,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {preprint},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1601.04824 },
title = {{Atomic saturation of reduced powers}},
},

@article{Sh:1065,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL},
journal = {preprint},
title = {{On many simple $T$'s for $SP^{(*)}$}},
},

@article{GoMeSh:1066,
author = {Goldstern, Martin and  Mejia, Diego and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Goldstern, Martin and Mej\'{\i}a, Diego A. and Shelah,
 Saharon},
fromwhere = {AT,AT,IL},
journal = {Proceedings of the AMS},
note = { arxiv:math.LO/1504.04192 },
pages = {4025--4042},
title = {{The left side of Cicho\'n's Diagram}},
volume = {144},
year = {2016},
},

@article{HwSh:1067,
author = {Horowitz, Haim and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Horowitz, Haim and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IL,IL},
journal = {preprint},
title = {{Saccharinity with ccc}},
},

@article{KmSh:1068,
author = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
trueauthor = {Kumar, Ashutosh and Shelah, Saharon},
fromwhere = {IN,IL},
journal = {Advances in Mathematics},
title = {{A transversal of full outer measure}},
volume = {submitted},
},
```

Here the file log

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

Prozess endete normal
```

[image: Log file]

I am using a MacOS Sierra, Version 10.12.6 (16G29). My editor is TexStudio. I have installed mactex.

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You chose another backend. Do not run bibtex, but biber on that document.

Comment: You need to make your editor run Biber for you and not BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Comment: Note that since you use `biblatex` you don't need to put the arXiv info into the `note` field, you can use `eprint` instead.

Comment: @moewe thank you, that answered my question <3 (TeXStudio > Preferences > Erzeugen > Biber (instead of BibTex).

Comment: Glad I could help. I voted to close your question as a duplicate of the one that helped you. (I removed [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/) from the list of duplicates, it is related but not the main issue here.)